# restrict link to open same link once again

Tags: javascript, html

I have one link example

```
<a href="xyz.html" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```

When ever i clicks on "Click Here" I can able to open new tab opens with xyz.html page.

My problem is if I have already exist the page with same link, I don't want to open once again.

Is is possible to restrict like this.

please some one help me.

Thanks.

Comment: ?The answer below does what you require. ACCEPT IT if you agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set as target a name. The Browser should load the Page in this named Window.

```
<a href="xyz.html" target="mynewwindow">Click Here</a>
```